# How to delete an struct of array, and the last index cannot be replaced by the others?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

i have problem here. I have a program that have 4 options which is add,swap,delete1, and delete2. The difference between delete1 and delete2 is : in delete1, you can do deletion on an elements of array of struct, but its last index can be replaced. On delete2, its also do some deletion, but its last index could not be replaced by others element. How can I solve it? Here is my last code :

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

typedef struct personData
{
    char name[27];
    char gender[27];

    int unique;
} DATA;

DATA persons[105];
int sizeStruct = 0;
int delIndex,delIndex2;
int indexSwitchA,indexSwitchB;

void add(){
    sizeStruct++;
    scanf("%[^\n]",persons[sizeStruct].name);getchar();
    scanf("%[^\n]",persons[sizeStruct].gender);getchar();
}

void change(){
    scanf("%d %d",&indexSwitchA,&indexSwitchB); getchar();
    struct personData temp;
    temp = persons[indexSwitchA];
    persons[indexSwitchA] = persons[indexSwitchB];
    persons[indexSwitchB] = temp;
}

void delElement(){
    sizeStruct--;
    scanf("%d",&delIndex2); getchar();
    int i;
    for(i = delIndex; strcmp(persons[i+1].name,"") != 0;  i++){
        strcpy(persons[delIndex2].name,persons[delIndex2 + 1].name);
        strcpy(persons[delIndex2].gender,persons[delIndex2 + 1].gender);
    }
    strcpy(persons[i].name,"");
    strcpy(persons[i].gender,"");
}

int delIndex2;
void delElementC4(){
    int i = 0;
    scanf("%d",&delIndex2); getchar();
    for(i = delIndex2; strcmp(persons[i+1].name,"") != 0;  i++){
        strcpy(persons[delIndex2].name,persons[delIndex2 + 1].name);
        strcpy(persons[delIndex2].gender,persons[delIndex2 + 1].gender);

    }
    strcpy(persons[i].name,"");
    strcpy(persons[i].gender,"");
}


int main()
{
    int testcase,NumberofProgress;
    scanf("%d",&testcase); getchar();

    for(int i = 0; i < testcase; i++){
        scanf("%d",&NumberofProgress); getchar();
        switch(NumberofProgress){
            case 1: // * Add
                add();
                printf("~Added!\n"); 
                break;
            case 2: // * Switch
                change();
                printf("~Switched!\n"); 
                break;
            case 3: // *Delete from database, and its last index could be replaced.
                delElement();
                printf("~Deletedd~\n"); 
                break;
            case 4: // *Delete from database, and its last index could not be replaced
                delElementC4();
                printf("~~Case4Deleted~~\n"); 
                break;
            default :
                printf("Wrong Input\n");
        }

    }

    printf("Result : \n"); // !
    for(int j = testcase; j > 0 ;j--){
        if(strcmp(persons[j].name,"") != 0) {
        printf("%s %d\n",persons[j].name,j);
        }

    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: To me it's unclear what you mean by "...and its last index could not be replaced". Can you add a simple example.

Comment: `for(i = delIndex;` ==> `for(i = delIndex2;` ?

Comment: `strcpy(persons[delIndex2].name,persons[delIndex2 + 1].name);` ==> `strcpy(persons[i].name,persons[i + 1].name);` ?

Comment: In the `add` function I would assume that `sizeStruct++;` should be done after the new element is added.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `delElement` has some problems:

- you iterate from `delIndex` to the first struct with non-empty name. But you just read `delIndex2` with `scanf` before. `delIndex` is thus not set. As a global variable, it is initialized with 0.
- your index should be a local variable, not a global variable.
- you copy the name and gender of struct `delIndex2+1` into `delIndex2`. It is unclear what you tried to do there, but this will do the exact same thing over and over in the for loop.
- You clear the name and gender field of the element `i`. This is outside of the loop. The value `i` is most likely 0 initially, then 1, the second time `delElement` is called, etc.

This code is as confused as your explanation of what `delElement` is supposed to do. Is it supposed to delete the element at the position specified with the `scanf` ?

There are also problems with the other del function. One of the problem is that `delIndex2` is declared twice. The given code should not compile.